AHK1 UIA: How to get the name property of all child elements inside a parent element?
I have a window with elements like THIS
I am trying to get all of the child elements of a ControlType=ToolBar parent.  I have managed to do it with this:
UIA := UIA_Interface() ; Initialize UIA interface
el := WinExist("Virtual Desktops Switcher")
el := UIA.ElementFromHandle(el)
el := el.FindFirstBy("ControlType=ToolBar")
el := el.findAllBy("controlType=Button")

print(el.MaxIndex())  ;---> 3
print(el[1].name)     ;---> #windowtitle:Everything 1.5.0.1363a (x64)
print(el[2].name)     ;---> Untitled - Notepad5

But I am wondering is there a direct way to get the names of a child elements a parent has, something like:
UIA := UIA_Interface() ; Initialize UIA interface
el := WinExist("Virtual Desktops Switcher")
el := UIA.ElementFromHandle(el)
el := el.FindFirstBy("ControlType=ToolBar").AllchildNames()  

print(el.MaxIndex())  ;---> 3
print(el[1].name)     ;---> #windowtitle:Everything 1.5.0.1363a (x64)
print(el[2].name)     ;---> Untitled - Notepad5

AllchildNames() is just pseudo code, while I solved my need in this instance, there are many times I just need all the immediate child elements of a parent and reading the documentation, I have not managed to find a way.
dump()/dumpAll() is not ideal, as I then have to resort to string parsing to get the names only.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
